# Sphinx sort by video duration field

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm trying to make sort videos by 15min+ 30min+ ...

In my db i have the field "length" where is the video duration on seconds, i try this sql command but is show me no videos found but is wrong ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH('@(title,description) funny') AND length>=300 ORDER BY " . $order . " LIMIT " . $limit_set . " OPTION max_matches=" . $limit_end . "";
$videos = $SphinxQL->create($conn)
                 ->query($sql)
                 ->enqueue($SphinxQL->create($conn)->query('SHOW META')) // this returns the object with SHOW META query
                 ->executeBatch();
```

The html sql is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH('@(title,description) funny') AND length>=300 ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC LIMIT 0, 120 OPTION max_matches=120
```

The length field on sphinx config is set on:

```
sql_field_string = length
```

Comment: I'm not sure I haven't tried but the problem may related your field configuration, have you tried with `sql_attr_uint = length` don't forget attr is not fulltext indexed. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-sql-field-string.html

Comment: i try the command but not working ...

Comment: Which version of Sphinx Api do you use ? what sphinx mode did you configured it ? one thing just suspicious now, Match and @ is works in sphinx extended mode. You may check this related article http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html and http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/07/23/from-api-to-sphinxql-and-back-again/ this may help, and try to remove length >= 300 to be sure. Is the issue related with the part of length filter or not.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the `length` attribute to be numeric (`sql_attr_uint` for example), so can do filters on it.... `length>=300`

Once you have that can use the `INTERVAL()` function to do sorting.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expr-func-interval

```
SELECT *,INTERVAL(length,15,30,45,60,..) AS i FROM table1 WHERE ... 
   ORDER BY i ASC, WEIGHT() DESC
```

If I've understood your requiremnet correctly.